# how to use dependency injection to provide data that is required by several classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

several classes in my dll require a set of the data ( general configurations ) . these data are provided by the one who uses the dll **through implementing an interface IConfigs** . so data should be injected as a dependency . now I wonder how to do that .

Update :

sorry , if the question was not clear . the problem is should I have an **instance of** IConfigs in each class that needs it and using **constructor injection** ( that I don't like this approach ) or there is a cleaner way to handle this situation ?

Comment: There a plenty of dependency injection frameworks available with great tutorials. Which of these are you trying to use? My personal favorite is Ninject.

Comment: DI isn't for injecting data, it's for injecting implementations of functionality.

Comment: see for instance [Use Dependency Injection To Simplify Application Settings](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2009/11/23/use-dependency-injection-to-simplify-application-settings.aspx)

Comment: What sort of classes require the data? Service classes? Entities?

Comment: WHat do you mean *required by several classes*?

Comment: Which container you are using?

Comment: @SteveWilkes : these are some helper classes in my dll that need things like current user identity and IP ... . but I dont want to send these info through parameters nor using HttpContext directly in the class . so the user should provide these data to the dll . no matter uses HttpContext or a windows user data or hardcoded info.

Comment: Ok, but what's calling these helper classes? Service classes? Entities? Are the helpers static?

Comment: @SteveWilkes : yes they are static and being called by service classes

Comment: @joocer Nothing wrong with injecting data, so long as it's an "implementation detail" of the service class with respect to whatever interface it implements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use injection dependency by property.

If you use MEF :

Service

```
[Export(typeof(IServiec))]
public class Service : IService
{
 ....

}
```

Client

```
public  class Client  
{
    [Import]
    public IService Service
    {

    }
}
```

Nota : You add lines in order to register your catalog and container

Comment: You can use Injection by property in order to change approach, i updated my post

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want do register different derived classes with one interface, don't know what IoC Container you uses, but in here I uses Unity as in sample code, but most of other IoC Containers support using one string to differentiate registration in one interface. Assume you have:

```
public interface IConfig {}
public class ConfigA : IConfig {}
public class ConfigB : IConfig {}
```

So you can register both `ConfigA` and `ConfigB` to IConfig with different name:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IConfig, ConfigA>("A");
container.RegisterType<IConfig, ConfigA>("B");


public class MainClass
{
    private IConfig _config;

    public MainClass([Dependency("A")] IConfig config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use constructor dependency, use property:

```
public class MainA
{
    [Dependency("A")]
    private IConfig Config { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As your helper classes are static, you won't be able to use DI unless you use a `ServiceLocator` style and have your helper class retrieve injected values itself, something like this:

```
public static class HelperClass
{
    static HelperClass()
    {
        var config = ServiceLocator.Get<IConfig>();
        UserId = config.Get("UserId");
    }

    public static int UserId { get; private set; }
}
```

This is not considered good practice because your helper class then has a hidden dependency on your `ServiceLocator` being set up with an `IConfig` which contains a `UserId`.

I'd therefore recommend you change your helper class to be non-static, and have the `IConfig` it needs injected into it via its constructor, like this:

```
public class HelperClass
{
    public HelperClass(IConfig config)
    {
        UserId = config.Get("UserId");
    }

    public int UserId { get; private set; }
}
```

You can then inject your `HelperClass` into your service classes via *their* constructors, like this:

```
public class ServiceClass
{
    private readonly HelperClass _helperClass;

    public ServiceClass(HelperClass helperClass)
    {
        _helperClass = helperClass;
    }
}
```

This way each component can be swapped out, stubbed or mocked as necessary. If your `HelperClass` has no state of its own you can configure your DI container to manage it with a Singleton lifetime, which essentially makes it 'static' with none of the disadvantages.